# Initialize several variables separated by comma ','

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration, assignment-operator

Using C++14, if I want to declare and initialize two integers on the same instruction (using comma separator):

```
int i,j = 0;
std::cout << i << "," << j << std::endl;
```

Then only the rightest variable (`j`) is initialized correctly. Indeed, the compiler outputs a warning message:

> warning: 'i' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Of course the solution is to repeat it on each variable

```
int i=0, j=0;
```

But the question is:

Is there a way to correctly initialize several variables with only one assignment operator ?

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: There is in C++17, as Caleth shows. Before that, you can at least avoid repeating the rhs by using `int i = j = 0` and so on, but I don't really want to encourage that...

Comment: The equal sign in `int i=0;` is not an assignment... it is a declaration with an initializer value.  How do you distinguish the case of `int i, j = 0;` where you don't want `i` initialized and the two variables initialized to the same value case?  What should `int i = 0, j;` mean then?

Comment: To distinguish them then you can write them in two different instructions. But indeed, my question was more: if I want to create 26 variables in a row and I am too lazy to initilaize them one by one (int a=0,  b=0, ... , z=0), do I have a workaround?

Comment: I have seen in code something like: `int m = x, y, z;` and above this line only x is defined. For other variables involved in this line declaration/definition is happening right away. I'm looking for the official reference for this kind of C syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly not; it's a quirk of the grammar.

```
int i(0), j(0);
```

is an alternative, valid from C++98. If you don't like repeating the literal 0, then you could, for that special case at least, write from C++11 onwards

```
int i{}, j{};
```

Comment: And with C++ 11 you may also use `int i{ 0 }, j{ 0 };`

Comment: s/Sadly/Happily. Don't encourage multiple declarations, otherwise you end up with `int * i, j = nullptr;` etc

Comment: @Carl: even better than that, you can drop the zeros.

Comment: Yep! But the bad thing is that I repeat '{}' instead of '=0' ;-)

Comment: @GenghisCat: Yes but your not really repeating a literal value. That satisfies DRY programming to my mind at least. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 2):

In C++17 and later, you can:

```
auto [i, j] = std::tuple(0, 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

You could initialize several variables with one assignment operator, but not when declaring them:

```
int i, j;
std::tie(i, j) = std::make_tuple(0, 0);
```

Comment: And in C++17 and later, you can `auto [i, j] = std::tuple(0, 0);`

Comment: Well, if it's "not when declaring", then it's not an "initialize", is it? It's an assignment. The variables are left uninitialised between the declaration and assignment, which is bad practice, a risk, and impossible for non-assignable types. More basically, as worded, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @underscore_d Indeed, it is not an initialization, my bad. Regarding bad practice and risk, that's arguable and really depends on the context.